# Why can't I define functions(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code that I've written out is a very simple one just to test out defining functions. Whenever I try and test it out in the shell, it gives me the same error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    hello(n)
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

this is the code

```
def hello(n):
print("Hello")
```

Comment: You didn't indent your code correctly; entering that into a Python interpreter prompt gives `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. If I fix the indentation, then call `hello('world')` your code works just fine.

Comment: You need to show us *more* of what you tried to do. Did you write the code in a separate file? Did you import that code? Or did you enter that into your shell?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `<pyshell#2>` kind of implies there may have been an import statement before hand that's not quite what was intended... :)

Comment: @JonClements: Exactly. Without more context that is impossible to deduce.

Answer (score 2):

Python is based on indentation, that's why no brackets are necessary for things like function bodies. You need to put the print statement on a new line and indent it.

Should look like this:

```
def hello(n):
    print("hello")
```

Comment: The error does not match your diagnosis. There would be a `IndentationError: expected an indented block` exception instead. Most likely the OP didn't format their post correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to be proper indented. Hope you wanted to do something like following:

```
In [1]: def hello(n):
   ...:     print ('hello' + ' ' + n)
   ...:     
In [2]: hello('Alex')

hello Alex
```

Comment: See @Martijn's response to user2528556 - The error would be different than stated if this were the case